# Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException when try to create a new route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I try to create a new route in one of my module to correspond to a new Controller in my project.

But I got this error and I have no idea where it come from:

> While attempting to create shopmanagementcontrollershopmanagement(alias: Shopmanagement\Controller\Shopmanagement) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.

I got this Stacktrace :

> 0 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(634):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromFactory('shopmanagementc...',
>   'Shopmanagement\...')
>
> 1 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(597):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Shopmanagement\...',
>   'shopmanagementc...')
>
> 2 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
>
> 3 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(161):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Shopmanagement\...', true)
>
> 4 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(94):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Shopmanagement\...')
>
> 5 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>   6 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490):
>   call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 7 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch',
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
>
> 8 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340):
>   Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure),
>   Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
>
> 9 /var/www/routedudrive.fr/public/index.php(21): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
>
> 10 {main}

Here is my **module.config.php** :

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Backshop\Controller\Backshop' => Backshop\ControllerFactory\BackshopControllerFactory::class,
            'Shopmanagement\Controller\Shopmanagement' => Shopmanagement\ControllerFactory\ShopmanagementControllerFactory::class,
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'backshop' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/backshop[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Backshop\Controller\Backshop',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'shopmanagement' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/shopmanagement[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Shopmanagement\Controller\Shopmanagement',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'backshop' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            'shopmanagement' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is my **ShopmanagementControllerFactory.php** :

```
<?php
namespace Shopmanagement\ControllerFactory;
use Shopmanagement\Controller\ShopmanagementController;
use \Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ShopmanagementControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $sm  = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        //$merchantTable = $sm->get('Backshop\Model\MerchantTable');
        //$accountValidationTable = $sm->get('Backshop\Model\AccountValidationTable');
        $controller = new ShopmanagementController();
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

This is my **ShopmanagementController.php** :

```
<?php
namespace Shopmanagement\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ShopmanagementController extends AbstractActionController{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function indexAction(){
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

This is my file tree :

[image: Filetree]

If you have any idea where the problem can come, all help will appreciate :)

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution if it can help someone.

I just forgotted to reference my namespace in my Module.php file like this :

```
public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                    'Shopmanagement'        => __DIR__ . '/src/' . 'Shopmanagement', //This line
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
```